# Excel VBA - FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am following formula using VBA Code,

```
.Range("M2:M" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC2 & RC3 & RC6 & RC7,trip_length!A:F,6,False)"
```

But when I see the formula by pressing F2, it shows as below:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2 & $C2 & $F2 & $G2,trip_length!A:(F),6,FALSE)
```

It's all correct EXCEPT the brackets around F. And because of that, formula returns an Error.

I tried a lot but not able to figure out how to use static range (of another sheet) with FormulaR1C1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `.FormulaR1C1`, all range references must be in `R1C1` format.  Therefore, use:

```
.Range("M2:M" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=vlookup(RC2 & RC3 & RC6 & RC7,trip_length!C1:C6,6,False)"
```